# Trying to get svn logs and got this error: "simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error: Premature end of data in tag log line 1 "

Tags: php, svn

I'm trying to access svn log through the PHP function. I have tried many examples and I used [this](https://gist.github.com/elvisciotti/4586123) example also. Please find my example code below:

```
public function getLog()
{

    $cmd = "svn --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --trust-server-cert --username kk --password 123 log -l 5 --xml <svn repository path>";

    $xmlData = simplexml_load_string(exec($cmd));

    var_dump($xmlData);
}
```

But this is not working, an error occurs as seen below:

```
simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag log line 1
```

But I can access svn log using this command via terminal.

Comment: Is your command return xml? Can you show part of exec output?

Comment: Yes.It's a xml out put.
'<log>
<logentry
   revision="26">
<author>kk</author>
<date>2016-05-05T04:45:32.602490Z</date>
<msg>modified display.blade.php</msg>
</logentry>
</log>'